# Installation of GNU radio on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, gnu

I'm a beginner at this raspberry pi stuff . I cant seem to figure out how to install GNU radio application on the raspbian. The pi was working fine up until i tried to install the GNU using the command
$ sudo apt-get install gnuradio gnuradio-dev after which the pi doesnt start up. The screen starts and then keeps on rebooting. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you installed Raspbian with NOOBS, just hold SHIFT when booting on. Then you should be able to Recovery system.

Comment: How big SD card do you use? Is it big enough? Did you expand filesystem to whole SD card?